# Z-Index on Popper menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, z-index

I have a working example reproducing this issue [on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/rl97oo800o).

What I'm trying to do is do the 'sit below' menu as [demonstrated on the Material-UI documentation.](https://v4.mui.com/components/menus/#menulist-composition)

```
   return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div>
          <Button
            buttonRef={node => {
              this.anchorEl = node;
            }}
            aria-owns={open ? "menu-list-grow" : null}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={this.handleToggle}
          >
            Toggle Menu Grow
          </Button>
          <Popper open={open} anchorEl={this.anchorEl} transition disablePortal>
            {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
              <Grow
                {...TransitionProps}
                id="menu-list-grow"
                style={{
                  transformOrigin:
                    placement === "bottom" ? "center top" : "center bottom"
                }}
              >
                <Paper>
                  <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleClose}>
                    <MenuList>
                      <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
                    </MenuList>
                  </ClickAwayListener>
                </Paper>
              </Grow>
            )}
          </Popper>
        </div>

        <Button color="default" variant="contained">
          {" "}
          I'm a button that sits under the menu
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
```

The issue I have here is that the Button further down the DOM, from the menu is always on top.

I've tried manually adding `zIndex` to various parts of the menu - but to no avail.

I suspect that the issue is something to do with the transition.

Can someone explain what's going on here, and how would I solve it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I  removed the `disablePortal` prop on the Popper component :

```
<Popper open={open} anchorEl={this.anchorEl} transition disablePortal>
```

Which now becomes

```
<Popper open={open} anchorEl={this.anchorEl} transition>
```

See the Material-UI documentation for the [Popper component `disablePortal` prop](https://v4.mui.com/api/popper/#props) to see why:

> Disable the portal behavior. The children stay within it's parent DOM  hierarchy.

By default, the Popper component uses the React Portal API : https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component

Using the React Portal API, the Material-UI Popper component renders by default outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent tree, this explains why it resolves the overlaying issue.

The modified working code is on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/4qvzkplzl4)

Answer (score 13):

If anyone still looking to change z-index or if you want to keep `disablePortal` try the methods below.

**Method 1**

Give an id to Popper

```
<Popper id='popper-1' .... />
```

Now in your CSS file

```
#popper-1 {
 z-index: 5; // or anything higher
}
```

**Method 2**

Set `z-index` in Popper itself using `style` prop

z-index working code (with disablePortal enabled) [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-d14pi?file=/demo.js:1429-1448)

Answer (score 8):

for me following solution worked: adding zIndex to popper.

```
<Popper style={{zIndex: 10000}} open={open} anchorEl={this.anchorEl} transition disablePortal>
```

for me removing disablePortal didn't work

Answer (score 1):

As Suggested by @Ricovitch, remove `disablePortal` attribute from `Popper` element or set it's value to false
`<Popper open={open} anchorEl={this.anchorEl} transition disablePortal={false}>`

As shown in the material-ui [popper scroll playground](https://v4.mui.com/components/popper/#scroll-playground) example when `disablePortal` is false, the popup element is attached to `body` element, which is the default behavior. For example, your HTML structure will look like:

```
<body>
    ... existing elements ...
    <parent>
        <button onClick={openMenu}/>
    </parent>
    ... more elements ...
    ... attached popup menu for Popper ...
</body>
```

However, when you set `disablePortal` to true, it will have following html structure:

```
<body>
    ... existing elements ...
    <parent>
        <button onClick={openMenu}/>
        ... attached popup menu for Popper ...
    </parent>
    ... more elements ...
</body>
```

I hope this makes things clearer!

Answer (score -2):

mobile stepper: 1000
speed dial: 1050
app bar: 1100
drawer: 1200
modal: 1300
snackbar: 1400
tooltip: 1500

`<Popper    style={{ zIndex: 1900 }}    open={open1}    anchorEl={anchorRef1.current}  role={undefined}    transition    disablePortal>any thing in the popper </Popper>`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.